# Significato di "stroppo" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Per chiedere la grazia di poter tirar su testa, un anno nostra madre andò pellegrina al santuario della Madonna del Deserto, che è lontano da noi, sopra un monte dietro il quale si può dire che c’è subito il mare. Mi ricordo come adesso. Era un po’ che noi, alzata la schiena, guardavamo la processione delle donne sulla strada di Mombarcaro, quando esce di casa nostra madre, vestita da chiesa, e con un fagottino di roba mangiativa. Nostro padre le uscí appresso e le gridava: – Vecchia bagascia, non mi vai mica via con quello **stroppo** di pelandracce? – Lei si voltò, ma senza fermarsi e solo per guardarlo negli occhi.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "stroppo" in questo brano? Ho cercato questo vocabolo in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non hanno senso in questo contesto. Si tratta di un termine di origine piemontese?

Comment: Penso si tratti dell'italianizzazione del vocabolo piemontese "strot" che, secondo questo  [vocabolario piemontese](https://books.google.es/books?id=_CiBBomBtL8C&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=strop&source=bl&ots=mHuU7I6enE&sig=9Vkqepb5_ji3EjYHefGP8mgbAIk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi41bzdkNvbAhWnJ8AKHeziCFIQ6AEIDzAC#v=onepage&q=strop&f=false) significa "branco" oppure "certo numero di animali". Nel brano citato nella domanda se ne fa un uso figurato spregiativo per indicare il gruppo di donne che vanno in processione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Su questo [dizionario dialettale di Alessandria](http://alessandrialisondria.altervista.org/dialet-lissandren-dizionario-alessandrino-italiano/) viene riportato il termine stròpa:

> stròpa (s. f.). frotta, torma, quantità di persone o d’animali.

Essendo ligure con nonni originari del basso Piemonte ti posso dire che nel nostro dialetto si usa stroppa per indicare una grande quantità di persone, ma in generale anche una grande quantità di qualcosa.

> Si è mangiato una stroppa di ciliegie e poi è stato male

Nel caso da te riportato il sostantivo è al maschile ma il significato è presumibilmente lo stesso.

Comment: Secondo [questo articolo](https://dial.uclouvain.be/downloader/downloader.php?pid=boreal:81491&datastream=PDF_01) il significato di "stroppo" è "branco".

Comment: «L’influsso 
del dialetto ha lasciato delle tracce anche nel lessico de *La malora*; Fenoglio utilizza 
“censa” invece di “privativa”, “stroppo” invece di “branco”, “onta” invece di “vergogna”, 
“particolare” invece di “piccolo possidente”, “bricco” invece di “monte”, “rubarizio” invece di “furto”, “diffizioso” invece di “schizzinoso”, “sversa” invece di “contrariata”, “alla mira” invece di “al punto”, “genare” invece di “imbarazzare”, “schivare” invece di “tener da parte” e “sbardati” invece di “sparpagliati” (tutti questi esempi secondo Grignani, 97).»

Comment: Ottima fonte, brava!